# Redirect to port internally with DNS name in IIS

Tags: .net, iis

I have site on IIS using 90 port and I want to map it to the DNS entry name TestSite. For this mapping IIS web site has to be binded to port 90 and host name as TestSite.

Is there any way to hide the port 90 from the url and show it as http://TestSite instead of http://TestSite:90 in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Port 90 is not default port of site on IIS. So 90 must be add after host name in URL.

The alternative is to use url rewriting.
`http://TestSite` => `http://TestSite:90`

Create an empty website and bind it to `http://TestSite:80`.
Add this reverse proxy rule in web.config. Don't forget to enable proxy in ARR module.

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://TestSite:90/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

So this method actually uses a reverse proxy to proxy the request to the real URL of the site. Even if you change the site to any other host name such as localhost, the URL entered on the browser side is still `http://TestSite`.